# What are possible segmentation fault causes?

Tags: c++

this is my main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FlyingPoints.h"

using namespace std;

void read(const char* msg, FlyingPoints& f)
{
    int inPoints, outPoints;
    cout << "Enter " << msg << endl;
    cout << "Enter number of incoming flying points: ";
    cin >> inPoints;
    cout << "Enter number of spent flying points: ";
    cin >> outPoints;
    f = FlyingPoints(inPoints, outPoints);
}
int main()
{
    FlyingPoints left, right, result, ref;

    cout << "Flying Points Calculator\n";
    cout << "========================\n";

    read("Left Operand...", left);
    read("Right Operand...", right);

    cout << "Result: " << endl;
    left.display();
    cout << " + ";
    right.display();
    cout << " = ";
    result = left + right;
    result.display();
    cout << endl;

    read("2nd Right Operand...", right);

    cout << "Result: " << endl;
    result.display();
    cout << " += ";
    right.display();
    cout <<  " => ";
    result += right;
    result.display();
    cout << endl;

    read("Reference...", ref);
    if (result == ref){
        cout << "Result == Reference" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Result != Reference" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the header file

```
  class FlyingPoints{
    int inPoints;
    int outPoints;
    void updatebalance();
    public:
    FlyingPoints();
    FlyingPoints(int, int);
    void display();
    FlyingPoints& operator+=(const FlyingPoints&);
    friend bool operator==(const FlyingPoints&, const FlyingPoints&);
};
    FlyingPoints operator+(const FlyingPoints&, const FlyingPoints&);
```

and the .cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FlyingPoints.h"
using namespace std;

void FlyingPoints::updatebalance(){
    if(inPoints > outPoints){
        inPoints = inPoints - outPoints;
        outPoints = 0;
    }else{
        outPoints = inPoints - outPoints;
        inPoints = 0;   
    }
}
FlyingPoints::FlyingPoints(){
    inPoints = 0;
    outPoints = 0;
}
FlyingPoints::FlyingPoints(int in, int out){
    inPoints = in;
    outPoints = out;
}
void FlyingPoints::display(){
    cout << inPoints << " points available to fly." << outPoints << "      points spent." << endl;
}
FlyingPoints& FlyingPoints::operator+=(const FlyingPoints& f){
    inPoints += f.inPoints;
    outPoints += f.outPoints;
    updatebalance();
    return *this;//why do we return this?*this refers to the operator?
}
FlyingPoints operator+(const FlyingPoints& a, const FlyingPoints& b){
    //inPoints = a.inPoints + b.inPoints;
    //outPoints = a.outPoints + b.outpoints;    
    return a + b;
}
bool operator==(const FlyingPoints& first, const FlyingPoints& second){
    if(first.inPoints == second.inPoints && first.outPoints == second.outPoints){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is what happens when i run. 
Flying Points Calculator

========================
Enter Left Operand...

Enter number of incoming flying points: 500

Enter number of spent flying points: 300

Enter Right Operand...

Enter number of incoming flying points: 200

Enter number of spent flying points: 100

Result:

500 points available to fly.300 points spent.

- 200 points available to fly.100 points spent.

Segmentation fault

I can't seem to tell where this segmentation fault is coming from, can

anyone help please? Could the cout be the cause? - thanks

Comment: Really good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: but it just gives me a seg fault at after the right.display();, i'm not sure whats going on

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the problem is that the `operator+()` unconditionally calls itself, so is infinitely recursive.

To quote from the OP.

```
FlyingPoints operator+(const FlyingPoints& a, const FlyingPoints& b){
    //inPoints = a.inPoints + b.inPoints;
    //outPoints = a.outPoints + b.outpoints;    
    return a + b;
}
```